# Trying to loop a command to run multiple times

Tags: python

Im trying to create a program that deletes files after X days. I got that part working, but now I need to write a code that deletes the file they're located at ONLY if it's empty

This is for a server that is taking log files from builds, and those are getting placed in thousands of other folders. I need to delete those upper level folders if they are empty

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
import time

#for path you need to use the location of the log files
path = "C:/GroupData"
# Check current working directory.
retval = os.getcwd()
#this will list the name of the current directory
print("Current working directory %s" % retval)

# Now change the directory
#You will put the same location as you did for path
os.chdir('C:/GroupData/Temp')
workdir = os.getcwd()

# Check current working directory.
retval = os.getcwd()
#this will list the new name of the working directory
print("Directory changed successfully %s" % retval)

from subprocess import call

def get_file_directory(file):
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
#this code is getting what today's date is
now = time.time()
#this code is saying that files that are older than todays date by 7 days will be deleted
cutoff = now - (10 * 86400)

files = os.listdir(os.path.join(get_file_directory('C://GroupData//Temp'), "temp"))
file_path = os.path.join(get_file_directory('C://GroupData//Temp'), "temp/")
#this locates what the file name is and looks to see how long ago it was modified
for xfile in files:
    files1 = os.listdir(os.path.join(get_file_directory('C://GroupData//Temp//' + xfile), xfile))
    file_path1 = os.path.join(get_file_directory('C://GroupData//Temp//' + xfile), xfile)
    for xfile1 in files1:
       if os.path.isfile(str(file_path1) + "\\" + xfile1):
            t = os.stat(str(file_path1) + "\\" + xfile1)
            #m is how long ago it was last modified
            m = t.st_mtime

            #if the cutoff date is older than the modified date the file will be deleted
            if m < cutoff:
            #if the file IS older than the cutoff os.remove deletes the file from the path
                os.remove(str(file_path1) + "\\" + xfile1)

files = os.listdir(os.path.join(get_file_directory('C://GroupData//Temp'), "temp"))
file_path = os.path.join(get_file_directory('C://GroupData//Temp'), "temp/")


os.rmdir(str(file_path1) + "\\")
```

The code at the bottom works, but only for one file at a time, and I need it to do it as many times as possible so that it can delete all the empty files at once, as this will be run automatically

Comment: Where is `file_path1` coming from?

Comment: There is the entire code, its hard to explain without showing the entire thing

Comment: Are the directories completely empty? If not try [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

Comment: No, there are folders that are staying, due to them being younger then 10 days

Comment: So it works? you just need to run it in a loop?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work, but once there is more than just the 5 files I have, then it should work

Comment: I believe `if m < cutoff and t.st_size == 0:` would handle your "ONLY if it's empty" requirement.

Comment: That worked but it didn't delete more than one at a time